# Take text_filed value in a variable using controller and views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails. I want to take text_field value in a variable and variable define in the controller method.

When will I click on the submit button then the value of test_filed insert into controller method variable.

this is my **_step.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :validation_screens, url: candidate_capture_validation_process_path(@validation_screen), method: :get do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Role / Designation</label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
      <%= f.text_field :role, {disabled: true, :value=>job.title, class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Candidate Name</label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
      <%= f.text_field :applied_candidate_name, {disabled: true, :value=>applied_candidate.first_name+" "+applied_candidate.last_name, class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Apply Name</label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
      <%= f.text_field :emp_candidate_name, {disabled: true, :value=>user.first_name+" "+user.last_name, class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here I want to take `<%= f.text_filed :emp_candidate_name %>`

This is my controller **candidate_controller.rb**

```
class CandidateController < BaseController

    def capture_validation_process
        logger.debug "candidate work flow: #{params[:applied_candidate_name].inspect}"

        can_name = params[:applied_candidate_name]

        @validation_screen = ValidationScreen.new(save_validate_process_params)
        @validation_screen.save
    end

end
```

then I got this output

> User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` =
>   11  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 candidate work flow: nil

Please tell me where I am wrong, and what is problems

Answer (score 0):

When we send data and we want to save in our database. We use post method. You are using get method please change your method to `method: :post` in your `form_for` tag. And update your request type in routes file also.

Try this

`<%= form_for :validation_screens, url: candidate_capture_validation_process_path(@validation_screen), method: :post do |f| %`>

Comment: In my code i changed **method: :get to method: :post** and also changed into routes like this **get 'jobs/capture_validation_process' =>'jobs#capture_validation_process', as: :capture_validation_process**  to **post 'jobs/capture_validation_process' =>'jobs#capture_validation_process', as: :capture_validation_process**

Comment: Did it work?? If there is any problem. And if my answer helped you please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: But it didn't work, my question is when i click on submit button then my form controller method will be call means capture_validation_process  then i want to get text_file value in a variable before save like this can_name = params[:applied_candidate_name]. Please look my controller

Comment: This is your mistake you are suing semicolon at end 
can_name = params[:applied_candidate_name];
can_name = params[:applied_candidate_name]

Comment: i remove semicolon but still my problems is not solved. I have also try this logger.debug "candidate work flow: #params[:applied_candidate_name].inspect}" then i got this out put  candidate work flow: nil

Comment: It should work there must be problem some where else can you please share your route code also. And try using simple-form gem It will help you in writing your forms in easier way.

Comment: My routes.rb file is  namespace :candidate do  post 'jobs/capture_validation_process' =>'jobs#capture_validation_process', as: :capture_validation_process end please check this